# Send an SMS as a User logs in to the sql server database with valid credentials

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sms, sql-server-2005-express

I want to send an SMS as a User logs in to the sql server database.
is this possible in sql express? please help me with the code.

i would use a trigger for sending the message. As soon as the user would log into an sql database with correct credentials he would be send an sms on his mobile, message body comprising his Username.

For SMS what features shall i have on my PC. i have Windows XP and have a broadband internet connection. i would search for some free SMS APIs on the internet or buy one if not available,

but what's the whole criteria of implementing this task from bottom to top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calling application should send an SMS. It *knows* what the username is because these are required to connect to the database.

Generally databases do not actively interact with the outside world except with their calling application. This includes sending an SMS. There is **no benefit** is having SQL Server send an SMS here.

Comment: @gbn: sir, ok , you mean that sql cannot send sms itself. the code has to be written in c#. i have a winform in which the user will enter the userid and password which would be passed to the connection string , if valid then user will be successfully connected to the database and an sms would be sent on his/her mobile

Comment: @sqlchild: yes, that it's. c# is far better for thsi

Comment: @gbn: but is there any way in sql server without using c#, to do this task?

Comment: @gbn: sir, you din't tell me?

Comment: @gbn: what should i have for sending the sms. do i need sms api or gateway.

Comment: @gbn: sir, please help, what should i use, api or gateway, i have no knowledge about it.

Comment: Neither do I. We only send emails using SMTP.

Comment: ok sir, so for email can you give me some knowledge.am using sql server 2005 express, so there's no inbuilt feature to send mail, but my management studio is the latest one, so can i use database mail? i mean that for database mail , is sql server non-express necessary or management studio non-express would work together with sql server express.

Comment: so do you use .net to send mail? if yes , then please help me out with the code